# Is my Firebase Cloud Firestore database secure or vulnerable?

Tags: firebase, hash, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I need help determining if my Firebase Cloud Firestore setup is secure or vulnerable to hacks.

In the database I have a single collection called *userids* which contains many documents. Each document contains data pertaining to the user whose userid is the name of the document. An example of this is:

```
userids (collection)
    123456 (document)
        field1: "..."
        field2: "..."
        field3: "..."
    777777 (document)
        field1: "..."
        field2: "..."
        field3: "..."
    999999 (document)
        field1: "..."
        field2: "..."
        field3: "..."
```

The functionality I need to have is then as follows:

• Given a userid such as `userid=123456` a client or server must be able to read and write data only to the document with name equal to *123456* (the client/server cannot read or write data to the documents with names *777777* or *999999*).

• Under no circumstance can anyone access a list of Documents which exist in the database, or the names of any of these Documents.

The security rules I have to enforce this behaviour is currently:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Now, let's say that all of the *userids* in the database are actually SHA256 hash values which uniquely represent each user. Assuming that this SHA256 hash was known only by the user, would this setup be secure since to read/write from a document you would need the to know the users hash? Is there any way that someone could find out the names of all of Documents in the database?

Comment: Reasking on https://security.stackexchange.com/ seams better suited.. Also without knowing the application code we can't tell, as security is as strong as the weaked link so If the signin is leak or using unsafe session management the whole system after is simply leak ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current rules anyone can ready anything from the database. They can not only **get** each individual document, but (as far as I can see) they can also **list** all documents once they know the collection they're in. Since `userids` is not *that* hard to guess, I'd say you're quite open to abuse here.

More secure would be to only allow them to get a document once they know its full path/ID, and not allow them to list the documents in a collection. You can do this by using the more [granular rules of Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations), breaking up `read` into `list` and `get`.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow get;
    }
  }
}
```

This allows them to *get* a document if they know its complete path, but not get a list of all documents.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. With these revised security rules, are there any other obvious vulnerabilities to my setup (assuming that the creation and distribution of the SHA256 hashes is secure)?